# Something really wrong with mysql

Tags: mysql

I wrote this query to get the first and last names of Employees and hours worked for employees who work more than 10 hours on ProtectX from dno 5.

```
select distinct fname, lname, hours
from Project 
left join Employee on dnum = dno 
left join Works_On on pnumber = pno 
where dno = 5 and hours > 10 and pname = 'ProductX' group by fname;
```

But my results make no sense whatsoever.

```
 +----------+---------+-------+
 | fname    | lname   | hours |
 +----------+---------+-------+
 | Franklin | Wong    | 32.50 |
 | John     | Smith   | 32.50 |
 | Joyce    | English | 32.50 |
 | Ramesh   | Narayan | 32.50 |
 +----------+---------+-------+
```

First of all, Franklin does not even work on ProjectX. I get the exact same results if I remove dno = 5 which makes no sense at all. Same if I remove pname = ProjectX. Why on Earth is Franklin in there if he does not line up with the where clause? And also, what is with the hours all being the same? That number should only be shown for John Smith, but it is shown for all of them?

Comment: It looks to me like you shouldn't use `left join` which allow to return rows even if there are none. Also, maybe you should prefix your field with the the table name or alias (for clarity)" finally, we would need to see the content of the original tables to be able to diagnostic the problem properly.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/32a09d72f3e61413f6afe886b9f97d1e
https://gyazo.com/477f13199e6e9d060aedbf22e4945e8d
https://gyazo.com/fb3dbc06f86ef44d81f3f0b0400c5167
Sorry it won't let me edit my post

Comment: Is it normal that *"ProjectX"*,  *"ProjectY"* and *"ProjectZ"* all have the `dnum` 5 ? Also, is it normal that *"Ramesh"*, *"Joyce"*, *"Franklin"* and *"John"* all have the `DNO` 5?

Comment: Oh that could have to do with it, I don't know why it's like that. But what about the issue with hours?

Comment: Looks to me like your query don't know how to link what with what. I mean, the same `DNO` (5) refer to 4 different employees, the same `Dnum` (5) refere to 3 differents projects and the same `PNO` refer to 3 different `HOURS` (20.00, 10.00, 32.50) for the projectX (which is the `Dnum` 5 and `pnumber` 1)

Comment: So is joining tables not the right thing to do here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107175/discussion-between-jonathan-parent-levesque-and-thebandit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select distinct p.fname, p.lname, w.hours
from Project p
join Employee e on p.dnum = e.dno 
join Works_On w on p.pnumber = w.pno 
    and w.essn = e.ssn
where e.dno = 5 and w.hours > 10 and p.pname = 'ProductX' group by fname;
```

As discussed in private chat, the primary keys of your table are respectively:

1. `Project`: `pnumber`
2. `Employee`: `SSN`
3. `Works_on`: `pno` and `essn`

Your query was linking the `works_on` table with the `project` table, but was missing the relation with the `employee` table (`w.essn = e.ssn`).

Both those keys (`pno` and `essn`) are required to ensure the right association `Employee`/`Project`/`Work_on`.

As you can see, I removed the `left join`. Those are useful when you want to return all the rows in the left table even if there is associated rows in the right table.

**By example**: I want the list of all the employees even if they didn't worked on the ProjectX.

That is not necessary in your case, since you only want to the employees who worked on the project.

**Another common example** would be if you wanted the list of all the employee who **didn't** worked on the projectX.

Finally, I saw that the project reference is directly in the employee table (the field `DNO`). That mean that an employee can participate to one and only one project at the same time.

If you want your employees to be able to participate to many projects at the same time, you need to remove the project reference from the employee table and put it in an *associative table* as the following (the script is missing the right data types for the fields; they must be exactly the same as the table they're referencing):

```
CREATE TABLE project_employee (
    SSN VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    pnumber SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, pnumber),
    FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Employee (SSN)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (pnumber) REFERENCES Project (SSN)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

You can populate this table with a query as the following (of course, I cannot test it for you):

```
INSERT INTO project_employee (
    SSN,
    pnumber
) 
SELECT
    SSN,
    DNO
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

You select all rows from `Project`, regardless of their `pno`. Since (I'm guessing) `pname` is a column of the `Work_on` table, it filters out the part that's being `left join`-ed, but not the primary table you're selecting.

So just filter on the `pno` column (if that's a column of `Projects`).

Comment: pname is only in Project, I just put pictures in a comment (couldn't edit the original post)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.